# I am trying to match keycodes to the sent1Array. How do I make the forEach go to the next number in my array?

Tags: javascript, foreach, keycode

If I type the first letter("T"), I get "Congrats". If I type the next letter("h"), I get "Nope" because it hasn't moved to the next keycode in my array. I need to move to the next letter in the array and match it to the next keycode.

```java
var sent1Array = [84, 72, 69, 32, 81, 85, 73];
input1.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
 sent1Array.forEach(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (sent1Array[i] === event.keyCode) {
                console.log("Congrats");
            } else {
                console.log("Nope");
            }
        }
    })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment your current array index every time the end-user inputs the correct key. So, there is no need for a `for` or `.forEach` loop here. Instead, you can define the index of the current key outside your `keydown` event listener callback, and increment that manually whenever someone enters the correct key like so:

```js
var sent1Array = [84, 72, 69, 32, 81, 85, 73];  
var current_key = 0; // index of current key to enter
document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
  if (sent1Array[current_key] === event.keyCode) { // use current_key as an index for the array
    console.log("Congrats");
    current_key++; // increment the current_key index by one
  } else {
    console.log("Nope");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first step would be why is your for loop ending when i < 1? shouldn't it be i <= sent1Array.length?

Comment: `var sent1Array = [84, 72, 69, 32, 81, 85, 73]; 
    input1 = document.getElementById('root')
    input1.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    sent1Array.map(x => x === event.keyCode ? console.log("Congrats"):  
    console.log("Nope"))
    });`

Answer (score 0):

your loop is running only once it should run for `sent1Array.length`. also you could reduce the loop like this.

```js
var sent1Array = [84, 72, 69, 32, 81, 85, 73];
        input1.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if(sent1Array.indexOf( event.keyCode ) != -1){
           console.log("Congrats");
        }else{
           console.log("Nope");
        }
            
       });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain an index which will increment with your keypresses. Increase the index as long as the keys matches and reset the index (and the input field) whenever user starts to be wrong

```js
input1 = document.getElementById("input1");

var sent1Array = [84, 72, 69, 32, 81, 85, 73];
var currentIndex = 0;

input1.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

   if (sent1Array[currentIndex] === (event.keyCode)){
      currentIndex++;
      console.log('Congratz')
   }
   else {
      //Maybe you should delete the last letter or the whole string from the input here.
      currentIndex = 0
      console.log('nope');
    
   }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
```